# I made /usr/local/ world writable, is it secure?

Tags: permissions, chmod, npm, golang

I had problem with npm while using Go(lang) framework Buffalo, the framework couldn't run npm through "sudo" so I needed to make npm world writable using chmod. I ran the following command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/
```

Now my Zshel is giving the following error message, is it OK?

```
zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?
```

Comment: The message is very clear. In general it is a bad idea to mess with permissions of the directories used by the systems.

Comment: I knew that, but it was suggested by a very senior developer. 

https://twitter.com/bketelsen/status/817464433349971968

Comment: @InduPillai Notice that tweet didn't use `-R`.

Comment: Oh, how can I reset the permissions back to default?

Comment: /usr/local/bin is in the default search path. It gives a malicious user the opportunity to place a programme in /usr/local/bin that would run as a command instead of what the user intended and ultimately undermine the security of the system. For example I could create a script called sudo that when the user runs it, keeps a copy of the users' password so I could log into their account later.

Comment: Is there a way to change the permissions of all the directories and sub-directories back to the default?

Comment: You can reset them one by one if you can find a default list somewhere of what all the SUIDs and GUIDs of the files are set to.   Honestly, it will be easier to reinstall.

Comment: Reinstall what? the whole operating system? :'(

Comment: Yes, reinstall the OS.

Comment: @InduPillai don' t reinstall yet.  It looks pretty easy to repair. Have a look at my answer and try to fix it with some chmod commands. Do 1 level at a time (no -R) and match what it shows below in the answer with your system.

Comment: What if I change the permission of /usr/local/ to 775 from 777 ?

Comment: The problem is, deep in those folders there are a lot of folders and files that also have permissions of 755 as well.  Setting to 775 might work for now, but some applications might need the 755 to work.

Comment: You mean some applications may need 777?

Comment: I cannot see any in the usr folder that are 777

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a list of my systems /usr/local/

```
$ ls -lR /usr/local
/usr/local:
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 okt  7 09:33 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 okt  7 09:33 etc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 okt  7 09:33 games
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 okt  7 09:33 include
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 okt  7 09:38 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 okt  7 22:15 man -> share/man
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 okt  7 09:33 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 okt 15 15:13 share
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 okt  7 09:33 src

/usr/local/lib:
total 8
drwxrwsr-x 4 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:43 python2.7
drwxrwsr-x 3 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:33 python3.5

/usr/local/lib/python2.7:
total 8
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:38 dist-packages
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:43 site-packages


/usr/local/lib/python3.5:
total 4
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:33 dist-packages


/usr/local/share:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 okt  7 09:43 ca-certificates
drwxrwsr-x 3 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:42 emacs
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:43 fonts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 okt  7 09:33 man
drwxrwsr-x 7 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:42 sgml
drwxrwsr-x 6 root staff 4096 okt 15 15:13 xml


/usr/local/share/emacs:
total 4
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:42 site-lisp


/usr/local/share/sgml:
total 20
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:42 declaration
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:42 dtd
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:42 entities
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:42 misc
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt  7 09:42 stylesheet


/usr/local/share/xml:
total 16
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt 15 15:13 declaration
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt 15 15:13 entities
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt 15 15:13 misc
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 okt 15 15:13 schema
```

---

To fix /usr/local/ issue these commands:

```
cd /usr/local/
chmod 755 *
chmod 777 man
cd /usr/local/lib/
chmod 775 *
chmod g+s *
chmod g+s python2.7/*
chmod g+s python3.5/*
cd /usr/local/share/
chmod 755 *
chmod 775 emacs fonts sgml xml
chmod g+s emacs fonts sgml xml
chmod 775 emacs/*
chmod g+s emacs/*
chmod 775 sgml/*
chmod g+s sgml/*
```

That should be it.

- g+s sets the SGID bit (group sticky)
- 775 = rwx rwx r-x
- 755 = rwx r-x r-s

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this entire conversation and all related comments have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51368/discussion-on-answer-by-rinzwind-i-made-usr-local-world-writable-is-it-secure).